# Site to site VPN with dynamic xzlland static

Tags: vpn

I am configuring L2L VPN between two sites through the internet.
Site 1:
I have ASA with ADSL connection and dynamic I`dlls5szltldu`p 
Site 2: 
I have ASA also with two internet lines ,leased line with static IP and ADSL line with dynamic IP .
I have configured the VPN and it is up and running only when I configure default `t7z`route through the lease line ,but if I configured the default route through the ADSL the VPN will go down 
I have on both ASA version 9.4 and PBR is there but i am not sure if PBR can resolve that .

Comment: You should only use a default route on an Interface where you don't know, the addressing on the other side, e.g. the Internet. For a site-to site connection, you should know the networks on the other side, so you can run a routing protocol or configure static routes.

Comment: I want to use the ADSL for normal Internet traffic so I need default route and use the lease line only for vpn

Comment: Then you need to set up static routes or a routing protocol between the sites. I'm not sure why a leased line needs a VPN. A leased line should be inherently secure.

Comment: No it is called here internet lease line which mean symtric Internet connection with static IP

Comment: A leased line is literally a private line which you lease between two points. It does not use the Internet to get from point-to-point. In any case, you need to do proper routing over the VPN.

Comment: @Mr.lock what is your question? When the default route points to the ADSL do you want the vpn to go over the ADSL or still over the leased line?

Comment: I want when default route going through ADSL the VPN go over Lease line ,and because the other site has dynamic IP only i can't use simple static route

Comment: Does the asa currently have 2 outside interfaces,  one to the DSL router and one to the LL router or how are they connected? Do you have control over those routers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me recap what you are trying to achieve. On site A you got two ISPs. One Uplink is used for Internet traffic (A) and the other Uplink (B) should only be used for Site2Site VPNs.

You are trying to establish a Site2Site VPN from B to a site that has no static ip address.

One could argue that you could just add a /32 Host Route on B to ensure this is working but since you have a Dynamic Peer this wont work.

I would recommend using Security Context feature on ASA. Depending on your model and license you can segment your firewall into multiple logical firewalls. Since you would have a different routing table for your VPN context you would not have any problems.

Let me know which model you are using and if this was an option for you.

Comment: IPsec is not supported on ASA in case of mutiple context

Comment: This is not correct. The limitation existed at some point, but not anymore...

Comment: For completeness: S2S VPN in Multiple Context Mode is supported since v. 9.0 on ASA

Comment: So both contexts would have a default route, but share the inside interface? How would traffic from the inside get classified to the correct context?

Comment: We could assign different IP and use static route on the hosts for VPN subnet

Comment: Please do not use static routes on your end-devices. Just create a 2nd context and add a route from Context A (Internet Outbreak, routes Inside-LAN) to Context B (VPN Outbreak). Add a static route from one context to the other but make sure to use a transport network for traffic symmetry (in case you route from Context A to Context B using the same network your clients reside in, this will result in asymmetric traffic flow).